# Way of writing this direct proof

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

In Richard Hammack's Book of Proof, he writes:

[image]

For the text I highlighted, wouldn't it be more accurate to say:

> Then $x=2a+1$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: imo, NO. Here, *some* implies that a is only one integer whereas *all* would imply that x is not a number but a set of numbers

Comment: No.  By definition: $x$ is odd $\iff \exists a\in\mathbb Z:x=2a+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. No number is equal to $2a+1$ for **all** $a\in\Bbb Z$. How could that be, since $2\times1+1\ne2\times2+1$?

Answer (score 3):

No, $x$ is a fixed odd integer, hence there is unique integer $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that: $x=2a+1$.

The claim "Then $x=2a+1$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}$" means that if you choose $a=5$ and $a=89$, then $x=11$ and $179$, those are odd numbers but then $x$ is not a fixed odd number.

The right way to say it is: $A:\{x\in \mathbb{Z}\mid \exists a\in\mathbb{Z}: x=2a+1\}$ is the set of odd numbers.

Answer (score 1):

No. To say that $x = 2a + 1$ for **all** $a \in \Bbb{Z}$ would be to say that $x = 2a + 1$ is simultaneously true for every possible integer you substitute into $a$. For example, it would be true that $x = 2(1) + 1$, and it would also be true that $x = 2(100) + 1$. But, together, this implies
$$201 = 2(100) + 1 = x = 2(1) + 1 = 3,$$
a blatant contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

In the context of that highlighted sentence, we have been introduced to some fixed odd integer $x$. We do not know its value, but we know that it is odd, so we know that it has to be $2a+1$ for **some** integer $a$, i.e. we can find an integer $a$ such that $x = 2a+1$.

For example, if $x=3$, then $x = 2a+1$ for $a = 1$.